# how can i make a text center while the other is on the left

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make the word menu centered while the rest left aligned.

```
def menu_page():
    menu_page_frame = tk.Frame(m_f, bg="#A68367")

    tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text="\n MENU", font=("times", 30), bg="#A68367", fg="#3E2416").pack(pady=5)

    menu = {
        "\n Americano": 10, "Cappuccino": 24, "Flat White": 22,
        "Caramel Latte": 25, "Spanish Latte": 22, "Espresso": 20, "Cold Brew": 20}

    for item, price in menu.items():
        tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text=f"{item}: {price} riyals: <20", font=("times", 18), bg="#A68367", fg="#794C30").pack(pady=5)

    menu_page_frame.pack(pady=5)
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
def menu_page():
    menu_page_frame = tk.Frame(m_f, bg="#A68367")

    # Centered label
    tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text="\n MENU", font=("times", 30), bg="#A68367", fg="#3E2416").pack(pady=5, anchor="center")

    menu = {
        "\n Americano": 10, "Cappuccino": 24, "Flat White": 22,
        "Caramel Latte": 25, "Spanish Latte": 22, "Espresso": 20, "Cold Brew": 20
    }

    for item, price in menu.items():
        # Left-aligned labels
        tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text=f"{item}: {price} riyals", font=("times", 18), bg="#A68367", fg="#794C30").pack(pady=5, anchor="w")

    menu_page_frame.pack(pady=5)
```

Comment: you got three answers and could click on accept for the one that helped most

Answer (score 1):

You can use tk.Text to show all menu items instead of lots of labels, then it becomes easier to align.
Using fill='both' and expand=True for frames and the text widget, ensures they expand and fill the available space. Use root.minsize to prevent the window from ending up small.

```
import tkinter as tk

def menu_page():
    menu_page_frame = tk.Frame(m_f, bg="#A68367")
    menu_page_frame.pack(pady=5, fill='both', expand=True)

    # Centered 'MENU' label
    tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text="MENU", font=("times", 30), bg="#A68367", fg="#3E2416").pack()

    # Text widget for menu items, with no border or highlight
    menu_text = tk.Text(menu_page_frame, font=("times", 18), bg="#A68367", fg="#794C30", height=10, width=30,
                        borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    menu_text.pack(pady=10, fill='both', expand=True)

    menu = {
        "Americano": 10, "Cappuccino": 24, "Flat White": 22,
        "Caramel Latte": 25, "Spanish Latte": 22, "Espresso": 20, "Cold Brew": 20
    }

    # Adding menu items to the text widget
    for item, price in menu.items():
        menu_text.insert(tk.END, f"{item}: {price} riyals\n")
    menu_text.config(state='disabled')  # Make the text widget read-only

# Main application window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Menu Page")

# Define m_f as a frame in the root window
m_f = tk.Frame(root)
m_f.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# Set a minimum size for the window
root.minsize(400, 300)

# Call the function to create the menu page
menu_page()

root.mainloop()
```

Results in:
[image: new menu]

Edit:
A visual representation  of which element in the code above gets shown where on the screen, could help you to integrate it into your code, or the other way around.

[image: code element location on screen]

When you will want to start adding more elements, it helps to combine the pack method with a grid. Using a grid makes it easy to add all kinds of elements at the locations you want, without all the locations being dependent on each other and messing each other up. The only thing is that you need to learn a bit how the grid works. You can check out how to use a grid in many places like https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/

The more other elements you want to integrate, the handier a grid gets. Here is an example of the same kind of visual representation as above, but how it would look in a grid:
[image]

Comment: the thing is i couldn't combine this code with the rest of my code! is these any way to help with that?

Comment: Check out the visual representation I added in the edit of the answer, there you see which part of the code is represented where on screen, in order to combine it with the rest of your code. When there are a lot of other elements, you can consider using a grid

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the f-sting format, find examples [here](https://cissandbox.bentley.edu/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2022-02-10-Documentation-on-f-strings-Updated.pdf):

```
text=f"{item:<25}: {price:>30} riyals"
```

**Option 2** For nicer format use `Frames()`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Menu')

menu_page_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#A68367")
tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text="\n MENU", font=("times", 30), bg="#A68367", fg="#3E2416").pack(pady=5, anchor="center")

leftFrame = tk.Frame(menu_page_frame, bg="#A68367")
leftFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

rightFrame = tk.Frame(menu_page_frame, bg="#A68367")
rightFrame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


menu = {
    "\n Americano": 10, "Cappuccino": 24, "Flat White": 22,
    "Caramel Latte": 25, "Spanish Latte": 22, "Espresso": 20, "Cold Brew": 20
}

for item, price in menu.items():
    # Left-aligned labels
    tk.Label(leftFrame, text=f"{item:<30}" , font=("times", 18), bg="#A68367", fg="#794C30").pack(pady=5, padx=5, anchor="w")
    tk.Label(rightFrame, text=f"{price:>20} riyals" , font=("times", 18), bg="#A68367", fg="#794C30").pack(pady=5, padx=5, anchor="w")

menu_page_frame.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unless you're using a monospaced font, you can't align the colons ":" this way, apart from making separate labels for the prices, which ends you up with the same alignment issue yet again. Using a grid enables you to do more things without more problems. On the other hand your approach is nice and short

Comment: You are right. I think the colon is not really necessary if you have enough space.

Answer (score 0):

The text in a label is centered by default. If you make the label stretch to fill the full width of the frame it is in, the text will be centered automatically. You also should remove the newline and space from the label.

```
# Centered label
header = tk.Label(menu_page_frame, text="MENU", font=("times", 30),
         bg="#A68367", fg="#3E2416")
header.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5, anchor="center")
```

[image: screenshot]